# How can I change font type and size in a boxplot with R

Tags: r, fonts, formatting, boxplot

I'm a beginner in *R*, and I'm trying to create a set of plots but the output must be **Arial font size 8**.

I've tried several approaches but none of them works.

I'm using a simple code such as:

```
boxplot(dados_final$ytot.n ~ dados_final$ano.f, col = "lightblue", xlab = "Ano", ylab = "Score", main = "Evolution", border = "darkblue")
```

Could you please help?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use *par()* as follows:

```
par(family = "Ariel Black")
boxplot(dados_final$ytot.n ~ dados_final$ano.f, col = "lightblue", xlab = "Ano", ylab = "Score", main = "Evolution", border = "darkblue")
```

Then the font of the plot will belong to the "Ariel" family

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Sure, would appreciate if you could accept my answer